# form $_post action value gets truncated after it passes through two forms

Tags: php, posts, mysql, forms, wpdb

There are three pages page1, page2 and page3. When I press submit on my first form on page 1 my group name field can be catched with $_POST['groupname'] in the destination page but in the page 2 I have another form which when pressed should pass the value of $_POST['groupname'] to third page. On third page I receive the group name value but the characters after the white space are truncated. Like if I have captain india as group name so I can receive only  "captain". Any idea how this can be resolved. Below is my code.

Form 1 (this is on page2 $_POST['groupname'])

```
add_shortcode('groupdetails','groupdetails');
    function groupdetails()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['Details']))
        {
            //max participants check start here
            global $form;   
            global $wpdb;

            //max participants check ends here


            echo '<form id="joinform" action="http://localhost:7777/wordpress/insert/" method="post">';
            echo "<input name='gid' type='hidden' value=".$_POST['gid'].">";
            echo "<input name='mygroup' type='hidden' value=".$_POST['groupname'].">";
            echo "Id : ".$_POST['gid']."<br>";
            echo "Group Name : ".$_POST['groupname']."<br>";
            echo "Group Type : ".$_POST['groupstype']."<br>";
            echo "Leader Name : ".$_POST['lfirstname']."<br>";
            echo "Address : ".$_POST['address']."<br>";
            echo "City : ".$_POST['city']."<br>";
            echo "State : ".$_POST['state']."<br>";
            echo "Zip : ".$_POST['zipicode']."<br>";
            echo "Meeting Days : ".$_POST['meetingdays']."<br>";
            echo "Meeting Time : ".$_POST['meetingtime']."<br>";
            echo "Max Participants : ".$_POST['maxparticipants']."<br>";
            echo "Children : ".$_POST['children']."<br>";
            echo "Description : ".$_POST['Description']."<br>";
            echo '<input name="Join" type="submit" value="Join" />';
            echo '</form>'; 
            }
    }
```

page3 (mygroup name variable is truncted after first blank white space on this page after submit is pressed on previous form)

```
add_shortcode('insertform','insertform');
    function insertform()
    {
    ob_start();
    global $wpdb;
    global $form;
    global $mygroup;
    $mygroup = $_POST['mygroup'];
    echo $mygroup;  //mygroup name value is truncated
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `echo "<input name='mygroup' type='hidden' value=".$_POST['groupname'].">";` contains the full `groupname`?

Comment: Thanks everybody the problem got solved ... infact I was missing quotes around my hidden attribute and the correct syntax which worked is echo '<input name="mygroups" type="hidden" value="'.$_POST['groupname'].'">';

Comment: @GentlemanMax I am really grateful to you !!

Answer (score 1):

I was missing quotes around my hidden attribute in my html form. The correct syntax is

```
echo "<input name='mygroup' type='hidden' value=".$_POST['groupname'].">";
```